# XSLT transformation through javascript Only for IE

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, dom, msxml

In Microsoft Internet Explorer we can use Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0 activeX component

to do xslt based transformation using the transformNode() method. We can load an xml

or xslt by the following method :

```
var activeX = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
activeX.load('webdirectories/xml/somefile.xml');
```

but can we load an xml by providing the xml as a string variable instead of providing the

location of the xml file? something like this-

```
var xmlFileContents = '<?xml version="1.0"?><books> .... </books>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a method `loadXML` you can use e.g.

```
if (activeX.loadXML(xmlfileContents)) {
  // now you can access DOM here
}
else {
  // check activeX.parseError.reason and errorCode here
}
```

Comment: kindly check the correctness of the below code sir:
var xmlString = '<xml version= '1.1'....';
var activeX = newActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
activeX.loadXML(xmlString));
activeX.transformNode('');
Will the above code work ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Microsoft only supports XML 1.0 so make sure if your XML has an XML declaration with the version number that is says `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and not `1.1` as in your sample. And I intentionally showed how to check whether the XML was parsed successfully so follow that line of code so that you can see any parsing error the parser might report to you. And `activeX.transformNode('')` is not going to work, you need to pass a DOM node with the stylesheet code. Also see the MSXML documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.